# Understanding an example of proof by Induction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, induction

The following example is taken from Kenneth Rosen's discrete mathematics book.

> **> EXAMPLE 13:** Suppose that a<sub>m,n</sub> is defined recursively for (m, n) ∈ N × N by a<sub>0,0</sub> and
>
> $$ a_m,_n = \left\{
>         \begin{array}{ll}
>              a_{m-1,n}\,+1 & \quad n=0\,and\,m>0 \\
>              a_{m,n-1} & \quad n>0
>          \end{array}
>      \right. $$
>
> Show that a<sub>m,n</sub>=m+n(n+1)/2  for all (m,n) ∈ **N×N**,that
>   is,for all pairs of nonnegative integers.
>
> **Solution**:We can prove that a<sub>m,n</sub> =m+n(n+1)/2 using a generalized version of mathematical induction. The basis step requires
>   that we show that this formula is valid when (m, n) = (0, 0). The
>   induction step requires that we show that if the formula holds for all
>   pairs smaller than (m, n) in the lexicographic ordering of **N × N**,
>   then it also holds for (m, n).
>
> **BASIS STEP:** Let (m, n) = (0, 0). Then by the basis case of the recursive definition of a<sub>m,n</sub> we have a<sub>0,0</sub> =0.
>   Furthermore, when m=n=0, m+n(n+1)/2= 0+(0·1)/2=0. This completes the
>   basis step.
>
> **INDUCTIVE STEP:** Suppose that a<sub>m',n'</sub> = m′ + n′(n′ + 1)/2 whenever (m′, n′) is less than (m, n) in the lexicographic ordering of
>   **N × N.** By the recursive definition, if n = 0, then a<sub>m,n</sub> = a<sub>m-1,n</sub> + 1. Because (m − 1, n) is smaller than (m, n), the inductive hypothesis tells us that a<sub>m-1,n</sub>
>   =m−1+n(n+1)/2, so that am,n =m−1+n(n+1)/2+1= m + n(n + 1)/2, giving us the desired equality. Now suppose that n > 0, so a<sub>m,n</sub> =
>   a<sub>m,n-1</sub> + n. Because (m, n − 1) is smaller than (m, n), the
>   inductive hypothesis tells us that a<sub>m,n-1</sub> = m+(n−1)n/2, so
>   a<sub>m,n</sub> =m+(n−1)n/2+n=m+(n −n+2n)/2=m+n(n+1)/2.
>   This finishes the inductive step.

I have problem understanding the inductive step that how the both cases 
 n = 0, a<sub>m,n</sub> = a<sub>m-1,n</sub> + 1 and n > 0, so a<sub>m,n</sub> =
 a<sub>m,n-1</sub> + n. are equal to m+n(n+1)/2.

I have tried to solve these two cases algebraically but they are not making any sense to me I want to know what is the logic behind proving the in both cases of inductive steps we get m+n(n+1)/2

Comment: Yes I know about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Long comment* : please, take care of the correct reading of formulas…

The inductive step is :

> assume that $a_{m',n'} = m' +\dfrac { n′(n′ + 1)} {2}$ whenever $(m′, n′) < (m, n)$ in the lexicographic ordering.

Now, we have to consider two cases :

*(i)* $n=0$ (obviously $m >0$, because otherwise we have agian the base case).

For $n=0$, by the recursive definition, we have that $a_{m,n} = a_{m-1,n}+1$.

> Because $(m−1, n) < (m, n)$, the inductive hypothesis tells us that $a_{m-1,n}=(m-1) + \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}$,

and thus $a_{m,n} = (m-1) + \dfrac {n(n+1)}{2}+1 = m + \dfrac {n(n + 1)}{2}$, giving us the desired equality.

*(ii)* $n >0$.

Comment: Thank you now it has started to make sense

Comment: @sachal - you are welcome :-)